# How to smoothen accelerometer and orientation sensor values in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on a desktop game with mobile phone as controller. The game is developed in Unity 3D and uses SensoDuino Android app to send Accelerometer and Orientation sensor values through bluetooth. The values are sent at a frequency of 100ms. But there is a lag between the phone movement and its reflection in the game. How can I reduce the lag and map the movement on a 1:1 scale without any jerks or jumps. Here is the code that I am using -

After the serialport connection is made, the following code is used to read data from the port

```
void recData() {
    if ((sp != null) && (sp.IsOpen)) {
        byte tmp;
        string data = "";
        string avalues="";
        tmp = (byte) sp.ReadByte();
        while(tmp !=255) {
            data+=((char)tmp);
            tmp = (byte) sp.ReadByte();
            if((tmp=='>') && (data.Length > 30)){
                avalues = data;
                parseValues(avalues);
                data="";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since Unity does not allow access of objects on the main thread from another, I set a boolean variable `moveObject = true` in `parseValues()` (to convert incoming string into float). This boolean is checked in `Update()` function and if it is true the following function is used to move the object.

```
void moveObj(float x, float y) {
        speed = 15.0f;
        Vector3 move = Vector3.zero ;
        move.x = x;
        move.y = y;
        move.Normalize();
        // low pass filter
        prevY = (0.8f * prevY) + ((1.0f - 0.8f) * move.y);
        prevX = (0.8f * prevX) + ((1.0f - 0.8f) * move.x);

        transform.Translate((-prevX * speed) * Time.deltaTime,(prevY * speed)* Time.deltaTime, -0.1f, Space.World);
        readyToMove = false;
```

I tried to use a simple low pass filter to smoothen the values and use translate to move the object. The problem is there is no 1:1 movement mapping. There is a lag. How can I fix this? How can I access objects in the main thread from another thread?

Comment: Have you tried a first order filter

Answer (score 1):

To solve the "lag", you could use the available interpolation functions.

```
Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity, time);
```

**Alternatives:**

```
Vector3.MoveTowards(start.position, end.position, time);
Vector3.Lerp(start.position, end.position, time);
```

Comment: Is it because of the movement? Or is it because the bluetooth data rate is async with Unity's 60fps? So the flag is checked in `update()`, so it is checked only 60 times per second. What if the bluetooth is sending more data per second? Much smoother right? If I put the movement code in a thread, it gives me main thread error.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with serial-ports on unity, but you're probably right. What's the baud-rate on the serial port? Did you try to increase it?

Comment: It was 9600, i tried with 19200 also.Only if I could call Unity API from another thread...Only if there was a free plugin :(